# Allowing Flexbox items to move closer together when screen size shrinks

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox navbar that I've been having great troubles with trying to make responsive (hence the question). I wish for the horizontal padding between the links to decrease as the page width decreases. With the main issue being that I'm unable to stop the contact us link at the end from being overlayed by the browser window when shrunk as shown in photo below.

I am also curious to whether this is possible without the use of media queries or if I'm trying to make things difficult for myself.

Hope someone with some more knowledge than me can help as I've spent far too many hours on this aha.

[Phone size screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07yW1.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/style.css" />
    <title>Home Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <img src="Images/logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo" />
      <!--Logo-->
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav_links">
          <li><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="./merchandise.html">Merchandise</a></li>
          <li><a href="./about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="./contactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="column">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui itaque
        repellat suscipit voluptas, ad rerum corrupti incidunt assumenda, fugit
        amet, recusandae officiis unde similique ullam. Quos magni cupiditate
        omnis dignissimos. Repudiandae architecto alias odio modi neque
        asperiores veritatis dicta ipsum! Enim cupiditate laborum voluptatem
        ipsa incidunt optio nulla facilis natus?
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
  <div class="column">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui itaque
      repellat suscipit voluptas, ad rerum corrupti incidunt assumenda, fugit
      amet, recusandae officiis unde similique ullam. Quos magni cupiditate
      omnis dignissimos. Repudiandae architecto alias odio modi neque asperiores
      veritatis dicta ipsum! Enim cupiditate laborum voluptatem ipsa incidunt
      optio nulla facilis natus?
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui itaque
      repellat suscipit voluptas, ad rerum corrupti incidunt assumenda, fugit
      amet, recusandae officiis unde similique ullam. Quos magni cupiditate
      omnis dignissimos. Repudiandae architecto alias odio modi neque asperiores
      veritatis dicta ipsum! Enim cupiditate laborum voluptatem ipsa incidunt
      optio nulla facilis natus?
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap");

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ddf2eb, #d3cdd7);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #ddf2eb;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.nav_links {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 10%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.nav_links li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav_links li a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", "sans-serif";
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #606d5d;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav_links li a:hover {
  color: honeydew;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: justify-content: space-between;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.nav_links {
    display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 10%;

  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.nav_links li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 1.5vw;
}
```

Do this instead. white space: nowrap was was causing it also your padding was set using pixels which arent responsive so i set to vw

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest such a way. Sample:

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
  .nav_links li {
  padding: 0px 3px;
}
    .nav_links li a {
    font-size: 11px;
  }
}
```

Link: https://codepen.io/en0ndev/pen/WNoWwOo

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap");

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ddf2eb, #d3cdd7);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #ddf2eb;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.nav_links {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 10%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.nav_links li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav_links li a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", "sans-serif";
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #606d5d;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav_links li a:hover {
  color: honeydew;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

@media (max-width:800px) {
  .nav_links li {
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
}

@media (max-width:700px) {
  .nav_links li {
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
    .nav_links li a {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  .nav_links li {
  padding: 0px 3px;
}
    .nav_links li a {
    font-size: 11px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/style.css" />
    <title>Home Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <img src="Images/logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo" />
      <!--Logo-->
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav_links">
          <li><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="./merchandise.html">Merchandise</a></li>
          <li><a href="./about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="./contactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="column">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui itaque
        repellat suscipit voluptas, ad rerum corrupti incidunt assumenda, fugit
        amet, recusandae officiis unde similique ullam. Quos magni cupiditate
        omnis dignissimos. Repudiandae architecto alias odio modi neque
        asperiores veritatis dicta ipsum! Enim cupiditate laborum voluptatem
        ipsa incidunt optio nulla facilis natus?
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
  <div class="column">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui itaque
      repellat suscipit voluptas, ad rerum corrupti incidunt assumenda, fugit
      amet, recusandae officiis unde similique ullam. Quos magni cupiditate
      omnis dignissimos. Repudiandae architecto alias odio modi neque asperiores
      veritatis dicta ipsum! Enim cupiditate laborum voluptatem ipsa incidunt
      optio nulla facilis natus?
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui itaque
      repellat suscipit voluptas, ad rerum corrupti incidunt assumenda, fugit
      amet, recusandae officiis unde similique ullam. Quos magni cupiditate
      omnis dignissimos. Repudiandae architecto alias odio modi neque asperiores
      veritatis dicta ipsum! Enim cupiditate laborum voluptatem ipsa incidunt
      optio nulla facilis natus?
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You really want to use `justify-content: space-between` which is completely flexible and therefore responsive without having to do anything else. If you put it on the head it will have space between the logo and nav and on the `.nav-links` it will have space between the nav links as you want.

```
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #ddf2eb;
}

.nav_links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 800px;
}
```